# cell value is no more editable when setting format

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

When I use `cellFormat` feature as defined here https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx-guide/blob/master/part1/5.%20Data%20Controls.md
my cell in the table stops showing its value, and is not more editable. 
My table looks like:

```
        with(tradeTable)
        {
            enableCellEditing()
            columnResizePolicy = SmartResize.POLICY
            isEditable = true
            column("Id", TradeEntity::id)
            column("Issue Date", TradeEntity::issueDate).makeEditable().cellFormat {
                style {
//                    if (it.dayOfMonth - LocalDate.now().dayOfMonth<=2 ) {
//                        backgroundColor+=c("#FFA500")
//                        textFill = Color.WHITE
//                    }
                }

            } ... more columns...
```

As you can see, `makeEditable()` has no effect even if I specified it explicitly, and even if style is actually commented out.
How do I make a custom style for a cell (or row actually?) without sacrificing eiditing capability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cellFormat` requires you to assign to either the `text` or the `graphic` attribute of the cell, or else nothing will be shown. Since `cellFormat` installs it's own `CellFactory`, it is in direct competition with `makeEditable()`. If you call `makeEditable()` you can however use `cellDecorator` instead of `cellFormat` to further customize your cell.

Answer (score 1):

All examples I’ve ever seen specify the `text` attribute in `cellFormat` explicitly, thus you should modify the code to:

```
column("Issue Date", TradeEntity::issueDate).makeEditable().cellFormat {
      style {
          // whatever 
      }
      text = it.toString() //possible transformations?
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped to show the value, not able to make it editable though